# error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io`

Tags: rust, runtime, rust-cargo, substrate, toml

I am building a substrate based project and I see some errors when I run `cargo build --release`.
The Toml file for `runtime` is given below -

**runtime/Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies.codec]
default-features = false
features = ['derive']
package = 'parity-scale-codec'
version = '2.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-benchmarking]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
optional = true
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.1.0'

[dependencies.frame-executive]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-support]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-system]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-system-benchmarking]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
optional = true
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-system-rpc-runtime-api]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.hex-literal]
optional = true
version = '0.3.1'

[dependencies.pallet-aura]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-balances]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-grandpa]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.1.0'

[dependencies.pallet-randomness-collective-flip]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-sudo]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-carpooling]
default-features = false
path = '../pallets/carpooling'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-timestamp]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-transaction-payment]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-api]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-block-builder]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-consensus-aura]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '0.9.0'

[dependencies.sp-core]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-inherents]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-offchain]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-runtime]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-session]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-std]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-transaction-pool]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-version]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[package]
authors = ['Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>']
edition = '2018'
homepage = 'https://substrate.dev'
license = 'Unlicense'
name = 'node-template-runtime'
repository = 'https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/'
version = '3.0.0'
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ['x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu']
[build-dependencies.substrate-wasm-builder]
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '4.0.0'

# local dependencies
[dependencies]
carpooling-runtime-api = {version='3.0.0', default-features = false, path = "../pallets/carpooling/runtime-api" }

[features]
default = ['std']
runtime-benchmarks = [
    'frame-benchmarking',
    'frame-support/runtime-benchmarks',
    'frame-system-benchmarking',
    'frame-system/runtime-benchmarks',
    'hex-literal',
    'pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks',
    'pallet-carpooling/runtime-benchmarks',
    'pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks',
    'sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks',
]
std = [
    'codec/std',
    'frame-executive/std',
    'frame-support/std',
    'frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std',
    'frame-system/std',
    'pallet-aura/std',
    'pallet-balances/std',
    'pallet-grandpa/std',
    'pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std',
    'pallet-sudo/std',
    'pallet-carpooling/std',
    'pallet-timestamp/std',
    'pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std',
    'pallet-transaction-payment/std',
    'sp-api/std',
    'sp-block-builder/std',
    'sp-consensus-aura/std',
    'sp-core/std',
    'sp-inherents/std',
    'sp-offchain/std',
    'sp-runtime/std',
    'sp-session/std',
    'sp-std/std',
    'sp-transaction-pool/std',
    'sp-version/std',
    'carpooling-runtime-api/std'
]
```

**The Errors that I see are given below.**

```
 error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/knoldus/Project/Carpooling-Chain/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-45b30cc25a28bf9d.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/knoldus/Project/Carpooling-Chain/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0d2b8d6c1590e857.rmeta

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `oom`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/knoldus/Project/Carpooling-Chain/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-45b30cc25a28bf9d.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/knoldus/Project/Carpooling-Chain/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0d2b8d6c1590e857.rmeta
```

**pallets/carpooling/Cargo.toml**

```
[dev-dependencies.sp-core]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'


[dev-dependencies.sp-runtime]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'
[dependencies.codec]
default-features = false
features = ['derive']
package = 'parity-scale-codec'
version = '2.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-benchmarking]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
optional = true
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.1.0'

[dependencies.frame-support]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[dependencies.frame-system]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
rev = 'd6c33e7ec313f9bd5e319dc0a5a3ace5543f9617'
version = '3.0.0'

[features]
default = ['std']
runtime-benchmarks = ['frame-benchmarking']
std = [
    'codec/std',
    'frame-support/std',
    'frame-system/std',
    'frame-benchmarking/std',
]
try-runtime = ['frame-support/try-runtime']

[package]
authors = ['Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>']
description = 'FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic.'
edition = '2018'
homepage = 'https://substrate.dev'
license = 'Unlicense'
name = 'pallet-carpooling'
readme = 'README.md'
repository = 'https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/'
version = '3.0.0'
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ['x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu']
```

***Can anyone help me out in this?***

Comment: Could you add the output of `cargo tree -i sp_io`?

Comment: Here is the output

Comment: `error: There are multiple 'sp-io' packages in your project, and the specification 'sp-io' is ambiguous.
Please re-run this command with '-p <spec>' where '<spec>' is one of the following:
  https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index#sp-io:3.0.0
  https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git#sp-io:3.0.0`

Comment: @Cerberus see if you can help

Comment: @AmanVerma please use https://substrate.stackexchange.com. As it will help it go public. Substrate needs your our support. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Solution for me was to add this to `lib.rs`:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

Comment: If you use remote crates, add `default-features = false,` in your Cargo.toml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should **uncomment** one of your customized pallet in runtime config like `Template:pallet-template::{Pallet,Call,Storage,Event<T>}`and `cargo check` again so that you can check what is modified pallet causing error. Or can you show all Cargo.toml of customized pallet. I'll help you.

Comment: I have added the Cargo.toml of the customized pallet in the question

Comment: see if you can help

Comment: Can you add   in Cargo.toml in your customized pallet                                                                               
[dependencies.sp-io]
default-features = false

version = '3.0.0'

Comment: Thanks, adding the dependencies in this format solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this means you have multiple versions of the same substrate dependencies upstream. As a first step, make sure all `cargo.toml` files have the same semver compatible version (ideally the same exactly). Then do a `cargo clean` and *remove* the `cargo.lock` file. Try to build again. If still not working, you may need to [update specific packages manually](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html#examples) via `cargo update -p foo -p bar`

Comment: E.g. "release-v0.9.25" has conflict with "polkadot-v0.9.26"